# calculate row percentage change based on previous date groupby multiple dimensions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have four columns: dim1, dim2, date, value. I need to calculate the value change percentage based on the previous dimensions (dim1, dim2) and the data order.

I tried the following:

```
df.sort_Values(by = ['dim1', 'dim2', 'date'],inplace=True)
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['dim1', 'dim2', 'date'])['count'].transform(lambda x: x.pct_change())
```

but returns nan.

Any idea?

Comment: Frist value of each group will be `NaN` can you please show some data to validate?

Comment: I don't know why, but my solution seems work....

Comment: Post some data from your data frame, the output of `df.head(15)` or an example where we can clearly see that there should be a percetange change.